# Missing Index Constraint Adding Foreign Key

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to define the foreign key in the leaderinfo table as UserID, which is the primary key in the usercredentials table.

```
USERtable="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS usercredentials (userID VARCHAR(255),username VARCHAR(255),password VARCHAR(255),stakeholder VARCHAR(255))"
mycursor.execute(USERtable)
LEADERtable="""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS leaderinfo (leaderID VARCHAR(255),firstname VARCHAR(255),secondname VARCHAR(255),age VARCHAR(255), \
        gender VARCHAR(255),ethnicity VARCHAR(255),address VARCHAR(255),postcode VARCHAR(255),telephone VARCHAR(255), \
        email VARCHAR(255),userID VARCHAR(255),PRIMARY KEY(leaderID),FOREIGN KEY(userID) REFERENCES usercredentials(userID) on update cascade on delete cascade)"""
```

Error Code:

```
mysql.connector.errors.DatabaseError: 1822 (HY000): Failed to add the foreign key constraint. Missing index for constraint 'leaderinfo_ibfk_1' in the referenced table 'usercredentials'
```

Comment: 'In the referencing table, there must be an index where the foreign key columns are listed as the first columns in the same order' https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html or make userid primary key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The column you are referencing in the leader table isn't indexed. You can fix this by making the `userID` column a primary key (I'm going to wrap the SQL here for readability):

```
USERtable="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS usercredentials (
           userID VARCHAR(255),
           username VARCHAR(255),
           password VARCHAR(255),
           stakeholder VARCHAR(255),
           PRIMARY KEY(userID))"
```